# Connecting a USB type A drive with USB type C port on a computer

Tags: usb-storage, usb-3.1-type-c

I have a [hard drive with a USB 3.0 type A port](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B00FCLG65U/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_fwjFAbA8F9PGQ) that I want to connect to my computer's USB 3.1 type C port. Unfortunately when I connect it with a cable, the hard drive does not even power on.

I have tried this with different hard drives, laptops and cables. The result was always the same. So it seems to me that such a connection is not possible. This surprises me, since I haven't read about this incompatibility and I can connect my USB 3.1 type C drives with my laptops' USB 3.0 type A ports without any problem.

Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: You have a Type-A port on the computer, but which USB standard is it, USB 2 or USB 3?  Please provide specifics.

Comment: Are you sure the port on the HDD isn't type-B? It's somewhat unusual for devices to come with a type-A port, and when they do, it's usually for attaching other peripherals, not a computer.

Comment: If the device is actually USB 3.1 that uses a Type-C connector, recall that Type-C can be any revision of the USB (2.0,3.0,3.1), then it's unlikely a cable that converts USB 3.1 to an earlier revision Type-A will provide enough power to the device.  (Meta, the "usb 3.1 type c" tag isn't accurate, because Type-C is compatible with USB 3 (provided you convert it to type-b)

Comment: I have added the USB version and enclosure information but I think it should not matter because of USB backward compatibility.